# Play store do not accept app less than oreo

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play

From November 2018 onward Google playstore won't accept app which are having minimum android version less than Oreo . I wonder is there any chance for the Oreo app to support android version less than Oreo, because there are a  huge number of customers out there under Oreo.

Comment: your question title and the info doesn't match. What do you want to ask ?

Comment: that is almost totally wrong. You are mixing up **minimum** and **target** sdk.

Answer (score 4):

Play Store requires TargetSdk to be 26 , not MinSdk version . So the apps will support lower versions as well . If you don't want to update your app then the changes will not affect your app by any way.

From Official blog

> Existing apps that are not receiving updates are unaffected. Developers remain free to use a minSdkVersion of their choice, so there is no change to your ability to build apps for older Android versions. We encourage developers to provide backwards compatibility as far as reasonably possible

[Blog post link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your app can have targetSdk less than Oreo, just not lower than Lollipop, as stated.

You'll have to spend some time with a bunch of if statements in your code for version checks when using newer APIs that are not available in older SDK versions in the case of trying to target older Android versions

Answer (score 1):

`...having minimum android version less than lollipop...`

They are taking about the Android Target Version (`targetSdkVersion`) ***not*** the Android Minimum Version (`minSdkVersion`).

So you can supply an older API level for the `minSdkVersion` and Oreo or above for `targetSdkVersion` and then at runtime perform API level checking to determine which SDKs to use.

re: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element